# Gitlab pipeline jobs in the same stage are not running in parallel

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

We have 4 deploy jobs in the same stage that can be run concurrently. From the Gitlab docs:

> The ordering of elements in stages defines the ordering of jobs' execution:
>
> 1. Jobs of the same stage are run in parallel.
> 2. Jobs of the next stage are run after the jobs from the previous stage complete successfully.

What happens, however, is that only one of the jobs run at a time and the others stay on pending. Is there perhaps other things that I need to do in order to get it to execute in parallel. I'm using a runner with a shell executor hosted on an Ubuntu 16.04 instance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your runner should be configured to enable concurrent jobs( see https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html)

```
concurrent = 4
```

or you may want to setup several runners.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem. I needed to run several tasks at the same time. I used everything I could find (from needs to parallel). however, my tasks were still performed sequentially. every task I had was on standby. the solution turned out to be very simple. **open file /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml concurent for the required number of parallel tasks for you.** [image]
[image]